# Htaccess Rewrite rule not working when secure (SSL)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a problem and dont know how to solve. tried a lot of changes but nothing is working.

I got a Parameter rewrite-rule that is working fine for years:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/.*
RewriteRule ^site\/(.*)$ /file.php?parameter=$1 [P]
```

So it displays the correct file.php?parameter=xy under the requested url (SEF parameter rewrite):

```
/site/xy
```

So far so good. BUT the whole rewrite isnt working when im requesting the page with SSL.

So this is working:

```
http://www.domain.com/site/xy
```

But this dosent:

```
https://www.domain.com/site/xy
```

Can somebody tell me whats going on behind? It throws a 500 server error (but i dont have access to the error logs - where i sure find the solution)

Thx in advance!

Comment: Why are you using [P] to proxy? It looks like a standard rewrite. Typically you use that when you want to show content from another site or URL not the same site. Also if mod_proxy is not enabled, that might cause the 500 error because it uses that for the `[P]` flag.

Comment: As i said its working for years and its not my redirect. I dont know much about but tried with QSA, L and so on....only thing was working is with P....but dont get me wrong: your post dont helps ;)

Comment: If this is on the same server, then check to see what has been changed. Also check your logs. You can't guess at the 500 error. you need to see what's causing by checking the apache logs.

Comment: ok big thx, i have to ask my admin! ...strange....as i said without ssl is it working....but anyway...thx